# dotnet.exe uses cache even when cshtml file is changed

Tags: c#, caching, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I deployed an ASP.NET Core MVC application to my server, and hosted it in IIS. Configured binding and everything is working. Here's the problem:

1. I change a cshtml file
2. I only upload that cshtml file onto the server, inside the relevant folder
3. I call the public action, that returns the `PartialView` of that cshtml file
4. It's not the updated version
5. I delete `cshtml` file from server, and call that action again
6. It serves the file, while file is not there anymore physically
7. I restart IIS, again file is served
8. I kill `dotnet.exe`, again file is served
9. I completely remove `Views` folder, still file is served

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Then you have server side caching in use

Comment: @BugFinder, server side caching should be invalidated with application pool recycling or with killing the process. Am I wrong? I did both

Comment: I checked the response, and it's not `304`, it's 200. I also checked response headers and no specific header related to caching exists.

Comment: Are you sure you're deleting from the right folder?

Comment: Yes, because when I stop IIS site, the won't serve the file. I remove `Views` folder from the same IIS site.

Comment: If you change anything, I would use `dotnet publish` command to get production ready files and push them to the server again.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might have this problem in future, it was because ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0.5 had [view precompilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) enabled out of the box.

This means that while we didn't want our views to be precompiled, we saw `*.PrecompiledViews.dll` in our publish folder that has been uploaded to the server.

Thus it doesn't find views from the `Views` folder, rather it loads them from the relevant dll file.

If you want to change this behavior, simply include `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` in your `.csproj` file.

Read more in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7625)